# jQuery Hover out-of-line

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, jquery-hover

I have a really simple JavaScript image hover script running on this website, but the hover isn't lining up with the image, and I cant for the life of me figure out why.

http://www.checkmyathletics.com/home/sample-page/

Does my error popout at anyone?

I can post anything thats needs,

thanks

```
;( function( $, window, undefined ) {

'use strict';

$.HoverDir = function( options, element ) {

    this.$el = $( element );
    this._init( options );

};

// the options
$.HoverDir.defaults = {
    speed : 300,
    easing : 'ease',
    hoverDelay : 0,
    inverse : false
};

$.HoverDir.prototype = {

    _init : function( options ) {

        // options
        this.options = $.extend( true, {}, $.HoverDir.defaults, options );
        // transition properties
        this.transitionProp = 'all ' + this.options.speed + 'ms ' + this.options.easing;
        // support for CSS transitions
        this.support = Modernizr.csstransitions;
        // load the events
        this._loadEvents();

    },
    _loadEvents : function() {

        var self = this;

        this.$el.on( 'mouseenter.hoverdir, mouseleave.hoverdir', function( event ) {

            var $el = $( this ),
                $hoverElem = $el.find( 'div' ),
                direction = self._getDir( $el, { x : event.pageX, y : event.pageY } ),
                styleCSS = self._getStyle( direction );

            if( event.type === 'mouseenter' ) {

                $hoverElem.hide().css( styleCSS.from );
                clearTimeout( self.tmhover );

                self.tmhover = setTimeout( function() {

                    $hoverElem.show( 0, function() {

                        var $el = $( this );
                        if( self.support ) {
                            $el.css( 'transition', self.transitionProp );
                        }
                        self._applyAnimation( $el, styleCSS.to, self.options.speed );

                    } );


                }, self.options.hoverDelay );

            }
            else {

                if( self.support ) {
                    $hoverElem.css( 'transition', self.transitionProp );
                }
                clearTimeout( self.tmhover );
                self._applyAnimation( $hoverElem, styleCSS.from, self.options.speed );

            }

        } );

    },
    // credits : http://stackoverflow.com/a/3647634
    _getDir : function( $el, coordinates ) {

        // the width and height of the current div
        var w = $el.width(),
            h = $el.height(),

            // calculate the x and y to get an angle to the center of the div from that x and y.
            // gets the x value relative to the center of the DIV and "normalize" it
            x = ( coordinates.x - $el.offset().left - ( w/2 )) * ( w > h ? ( h/w ) : 1 ),
            y = ( coordinates.y - $el.offset().top  - ( h/2 )) * ( h > w ? ( w/h ) : 1 ),

            // the angle and the direction from where the mouse came in/went out clockwise (TRBL=0123);
            // first calculate the angle of the point,
            // add 180 deg to get rid of the negative values
            // divide by 90 to get the quadrant
            // add 3 and do a modulo by 4  to shift the quadrants to a proper clockwise TRBL (top/right/bottom/left) **/
            direction = Math.round( ( ( ( Math.atan2(y, x) * (180 / Math.PI) ) + 180 ) / 90 ) + 3 ) % 4;

        return direction;

    },
    _getStyle : function( direction ) {

        var fromStyle, toStyle,
            slideFromTop = { left : '0px', top : '-100%' },
            slideFromBottom = { left : '0px', top : '100%' },
            slideFromLeft = { left : '-100%', top : '0px' },
            slideFromRight = { left : '100%', top : '0px' },
            slideTop = { top : '0px' },
            slideLeft = { left : '0px' };

        switch( direction ) {
            case 0:
                // from top
                fromStyle = !this.options.inverse ? slideFromTop : slideFromBottom;
                toStyle = slideTop;
                break;
            case 1:
                // from right
                fromStyle = !this.options.inverse ? slideFromRight : slideFromLeft;
                toStyle = slideLeft;
                break;
            case 2:
                // from bottom
                fromStyle = !this.options.inverse ? slideFromBottom : slideFromTop;
                toStyle = slideTop;
                break;
            case 3:
                // from left
                fromStyle = !this.options.inverse ? slideFromLeft : slideFromRight;
                toStyle = slideLeft;
                break;
        };

        return { from : fromStyle, to : toStyle };

    },
    // apply a transition or fallback to jquery animate based on Modernizr.csstransitions support
    _applyAnimation : function( el, styleCSS, speed ) {

        $.fn.applyStyle = this.support ? $.fn.css : $.fn.animate;
        el.stop().applyStyle( styleCSS, $.extend( true, [], { duration : speed + 'ms' } ) );

    },

};

var logError = function( message ) {

    if ( window.console ) {

        window.console.error( message );

    }

};

$.fn.hoverdir = function( options ) {

    var instance = $.data( this, 'hoverdir' );

    if ( typeof options === 'string' ) {

        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 );

        this.each(function() {

            if ( !instance ) {

                logError( "cannot call methods on hoverdir prior to initialization; " +
                "attempted to call method '" + options + "'" );
                return;

            }

            if ( !$.isFunction( instance[options] ) || options.charAt(0) === "_" ) {

                logError( "no such method '" + options + "' for hoverdir instance" );
                return;

            }

            instance[ options ].apply( instance, args );

        });

    } 
    else {

        this.each(function() {

            if ( instance ) {

                instance._init();

            }
            else {

                instance = $.data( this, 'hoverdir', new $.HoverDir( options, this ) );

            }

        });

    }

    return instance;

};

} )( jQuery, window );
```

```
$(function() {

            $(' #da-thumbs > li ').each( function() { $(this).hoverdir({
                hoverDelay : 75
            }); } );

        });
```

I also use Modernizer (im not familiar with it, but its not paste friendly.)

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please port here the relevant script

Comment: added to my original post, thanks

Comment: how are you calling the function? the `div` seems to be aligning with the `a` element instead of `img`

Comment: added additional function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a `margin-top: 20px` to your `.da-thumbs li a div` CSS, that will push it down `20px` so that it will cover the image exactly.

```
.da-thumbs li a div {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```